# Public MustOverride sub new(Param as type)

Tags: vb.net, overriding

I have  MustInherit class named ParentClass.
I need to be able to write the following, in a different place:

```
Function TheThing(Of T As ParentClass)(s As String) As ParentClass
    Return New T(s)
End Function
```

I would therefore write

```
MustInherit Class ParentClass
    MustOverride Sub New(s As String)
End Class
Class Class_Daughter1
    Inherits ParentClass
    Overrides Sub New(s As String)
        'do whatever
    End Sub
End Class
```

Indeed:

- if i do NOT declare  MustOverride sub new(s as string) , then the function TheThing does not know that any class derived from ParentClass does have a sub new(s as string)
- if I do add it, then it says new cannot be mustoverride

Is there any way of doing that? I tried using a Implements, but it didn't work out either...

PS: if I merely use

```
Function TheThing(Of T As ParentClass)(s As String) As ParentClass
    dim a as new T()
    Return a
End Function
```

the line with the new does not work either

PS2: this isn't allowed either:

```
Function TheThing(Of T As {ParentClass, iCreatable})(s As String) As ParentClass
    Return New T(s)
End Function
Interface iCreatable
    Sub New() '===> not allowed in interface
End Interface
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for a class cannot be MustInherit, but if you want to do something basically the same, you could do something like this:

```
MustInherit Class ParentClass
    Protected Sub New(s As String)
        Initialize(s)
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub Initialize()

End Class
```

Your Daughter class's constructor will have to call `MyBase.New(s)`.  This way Daughter class is required to implement the initialization and since the daughter class is required to call the base class constructor, you are guaranteed that Initialize will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed that ensures that the new is implemented... but compiler still believes that the type T might not implement New. Is there an interface (like iComparable, iConvertible ... ) thant means "that can be created"?

Comment: By making ParentClass only have one constructor and that constructor having parameters, any inherited class *must* have a constructor of its own that calls the base class constructor providing parameters.

Comment: Hi, this is true... but compiler does not understand it. Check my own answer to see the workaround I found :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer (from a friend) :

```
Function TheThing(Of T As {New, ParentClass})(s As String) As ParentClass
    Dim res As New T()
    res.Init(s)
    Return res
End Function

MustInherit Class ParentClass
    MustOverride Sub Init(s As String)
End Class

Class Class_Daughter1
    Inherits ParentClass
    Overrides Sub Init(s As String)
        'do whatever
    End Sub
End Class
```

Only thing I couldn't work out: I cannot write the following (classier but would be equivalent if it compiled) :

```
Function TheThing(Of T As {New(s as string), ParentClass})(s As String) As ParentClass
    return New T(s)
End Function

MustInherit Class ParentClass
    'nothing here
End Class

Class Class_Daughter1
    Inherits ParentClass
    public Sub New(s As String)
        'do whatever
    End Sub
End Class
```